# smart_ptr to attribute of class segfault

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, smart-pointers

I am wondering if this example would cause a segfault, because the dtor of the object is called an I am still holding a shared_ptr to an attribute of the object.

```
struct foo{
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> const bar = std::make_shared<std::string>("foo");

    foo() {std::cout << "CTOR!" << std::endl;} 

    ~foo(){std::cout << "DTOR!" << std::endl;}
};
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> ptr;
    {
        std::shared_ptr<foo> foo_ptr = std::make_shared<foo>();
        ptr = foo_ptr->bar;
    }
    std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it  it won't. By assigning a `std::shared_ptr` to another you are denying it from dying.

This operation `ptr = foo_ptr->bar;` will increase the counter of the shared pointer by one. This will guarantee that the dynamically allocated object on the free store will still alive.

**is it true even for attributes of a destroyed object?!**

Yes, This is true. In non-formal talk,one of the uses of dynamically allocated memory is when you want your object to live more than its owner (another object, pointer...). So , it is perfectly fine the that object will live after the container object died.

---

Try to execute this code. It will make it clear fro you:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> ptr;
{
    std::shared_ptr<foo> foo_ptr = std::make_shared<foo>();
    std::cout <<"References Count:" << foo_ptr->bar.use_count()<<"\n";
    ptr = foo_ptr->bar;
    std::cout <<"References Count:" << foo_ptr->bar.use_count()<<"\n";
}
std::cout <<"References Count:" << ptr.use_count()<<"\n";
std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
```

It will output:

> ```
> CTOR!
> References Count:1
> References Count:2
> DTOR!
> References Count:1
> foo
> ```

[Online Demo](http://cpp.sh/6nrkk)

Comment: so the object will be destroyed, but the attribute is still alive?

Comment: just a minute I thought it a pointer to the object it self not to its attriubute.. I am not sure let me check

Comment: @Exagon, yes. Precisely. That is what shared_ptr is for.

Comment: Yes it will still a live, I will edit to explain more

Comment: @Exagon: Just to be clear: the attribute `bar` won't be alive after `foo_ptr` goes out of scope, but `ptr` doesn't point to `bar`. Instead it points to whatever `bar` pointed to and THAT object is guaranteed to still be alive. Using a shared pointer to manage the `foo` object is just noise that is unrelated to the core of your question. You could e.g. just create it as a local object on the stack.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem here.  `std::shared_ptr` was designed to do exactly this.  If we look at how the code works you can see that

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> ptr;
```

creates a `shared_ptr` named `ptr` that points to nothing.

```
{
    std::shared_ptr<foo> foo_ptr = std::make_shared<foo>();
    ptr = foo_ptr->bar;
}
```

Now we create `shared_ptr` named `foo_ptr` that points to a valid instance of `foo` and `foo`s constructor initializes `bar`.  We then assign `bar` to `ptr`.  When we do that the internal reference counter of `bar` is incremented by one(to two) and now `bar` and `ptr` *share* the internal pointer.  Then we hit the end of the scope and `foo_ptr` is destroyed, when it is destoryed it calls the destructor for `foo` which calls the destructor of `bar`.  When `bar` is destroyed it gives up its access to the pointer.  This means it decrements the reference counter.  If it is the last `shared_ptr`(the counter is at one when the destructor is entered) then the pointer is also deleted, if it is not then it does nothing else.  Since the counter was more than one(it was at two because of `ptr = foo_ptr->bar`) the pointer is not deleted but instead it lives on in `ptr` since the ownership is *shared*.

```
std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
```

Here `ptr` is still valid as it shares in the ownership so there is no issue.  When the program ends we enter the destructor of `ptr` and see the reference counter is at one so the pointer is deleted thus ensuring that we do not have a memory leak.  So `std::shared_ptr` not only gives us safe copying of pointers but also automatic memory management.  This does come with some extra cost though.  There is a atomic reference counter to work with so it is not as small or as fast as a raw pointer but it is much safer.